# KVO observe AVAudioSession's recordPermission doesn't work

Tags: swift, avfoundation, key-value-observing

My application uses the microphone's permission, which is requested in another framework, and in the main application, I wasn't able to observe when microphone permission changed. I tried using KVO's observer but the application doesn't receive any events when the microphone permission is changed.

```
private var permissionStatusObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?

private func observeRecordPermissionChange() {
    do {
      try audioSession.setActive(true)
      permissionStatusObserver = audioSession.observe(\.recordPermission) { [weak self] _, recordPermissions in
        print("recordPermission changed")
      }
    } catch {
      print("active audio failed \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
  }
```

Comment: If microphone permission changes, the OS terminates the app. How exactly can you ever observe that?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Because the microphone permission is asked by once framework in my application, so the application doesn't know whether user accepts or denies the microphone permission. Therefore, I intend to observe KVO recordPermission, but I know that Apple doesn't support to observe this property

Answer (score 0):

Not going to work.

There are 3 possibilities:

- App never asked user for permissions yet. In this case you should present permissions to the user and wait for their response. In this case you need to define `requestRecordPermission` callback instead of listening to KVO.
- App previously asked user for permissions, and user granted them. In this case you can proceed working with microphone.
- App previously asked user for permissions, and user denied. Typically in this case apps show the message telling user to go to settings. And user needs to go to Settings -> Privacy -> Microphone and reenable the permissions, at which point the app will be restarted. So nothing to listen to as @cora mentioned.

Something like this:

```
switch AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission {
    case .granted:
       // start recording
    case .denied:
       // Present message to user indicating that recording
       // can't be performed until they change their preference
       // under Settings -> Privacy -> Microphone 
    case . undetermined:
       // Ask for permissions as explained below.
}
```

Or you can always ask for permissions like [Apple tells us to](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/1616601-requestrecordpermission):

```
// Request permission to record.
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission { granted in
    if granted {
        // The user granted access. Present recording interface.
    } else {
        // Present message to user indicating that recording
        // can't be performed until they change their preference
        // under Settings -> Privacy -> Microphone
    }
}
```

This is safe to do even if the permission is already granted (the callback will be back very quickly).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Because the microphone permission is asked by once framework in my application, so the application doesn't know whether user accepts or denies the microphone permission. Therefore, I intend to observe KVO recordPermission, but I know that Apple doesn't support to observe this property.

Comment: Like I said, asking for permission is generally safe. However, you can also always check the permission with `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission` instead of asking. No point to observe as it won't change during the lifetime of the app